# How to vectorize this for loop matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, vectorization

```
divisible = 0;
low = input('Start Value: ');
high = input('End Value: ');
divisor = input('Divisor: ');
mask = mod([low:high],divisor);

  for index = low:high
     if mask(index) == 0
        divisible = divisible + 1;
     end
  end
```

The idea is to count the number of times there is no remainder.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a one line solution:

```
%#Set the inputs
LB = 3;
UB = 28;
Divisor = 3;

%#A one-line solution
Count = sum(mod((LB:UB)', Divisor) == 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

try this line instead of the loop

```
 divisible = sum(mask(low:high)==0);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your routine will give you an error whenever `low > 1` because mask will start at 1 and have high - low + 1 elements (and when asking for mask(high) you will get and error).

Second, you almost got the answer yourself:

`mask = mod([low:high],divisor);`

will be a vector that contains 0 that indicate that the corresponding value is divisible by the divisor.  If you do `mask == 0` you will get a vector of 1 and 0 (true or false).

The next step is to add all these 1 and 0:

`sum(mask==0)`

and so you elliminate the for...end loop